# matplotlib custom x-axes with custom number of ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

After years of reading stackoverflow I reached a question that I cannot find an answer to, so I am starting here.

I am using python and matplotlib and want to plot with the xaxis starting from 1, nothing else being changed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = range(1, 1000, 2)
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

This plots but the x axis starts from 0. I tried to provide an x axis with

```
y = range(1, 1000, 2)
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(range(1, len(y)+1), y)
plt.show()
```

but this does not change the x axis itself.

Another way I tried is to use plt.xticks and set the ticks myself.

```
y = range(1, 1000, 2)
plt.plot(y)
x = range(1, len(y)+1)
xstr = map(str, x)
plt.xticks(x, xstr)
plt.show()
```

But then I run into the problem of 500 xticks being drawn (or even more, if the y values contain a lot of data).

How can i simply plot the data with the xaxis displaying 1 instead of the 0 at the beginning, without the first element of the data to be left out or other data changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, `xlim` is not working, but why not just leave 1 and 1000 on the xticks?

```
plt.xticks([1, 1000])
```

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately it does not solve the question if the values are too numerous. Using xlim with y values as y = range(1, 1000, 2) will still give 0 as the start in the plot. Does it plot with 1 in the xaxis on your machine?

Comment: @tkja I have a hard time understanding what you wanna achieve. Why are you plotting `y` alone rather than a proper `ax.plot(x, y)`. If you just wanna start the ticks from `1`, then the revised answer above should be good, no need to put a thousand ticks on the plot as you did earlier.

Comment: Simple and working. If I would have the power to upvote you, I would. Thanks!

Comment: @tkja well, apparently I have.